# Редирект с htttp на https и с www на без www

Tags: .htaccess, битрикс, редирект

При выполнении редиректа почему то получается 404:

Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/bitrix/urlrewrite.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bitrix/urlrewrite.php [L]
RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Подскажите, как можно исправить данную ситуацию?

Answer (score 1):

#### Если битрикс веб-окружение или когда apache стоит за nginx

```
#
#  example.com замените на свое название сайта
#

RewriteCond %{HTTP:HTTPS} !YES [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

#### Для ISPManager и/или общего случая, когда apache отвечает напрямую

```
#
# example.com замените на свое название сайта
#

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

работает стабильно почти всегда, но например для хостинга timeweb подходит это:

```
#
# example.com замените на свое название сайта
#

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-HTTPS} !1 [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```